# Safest way to limit current output of a signal generator

Tags: current, current-limiting

I need to feed a TTL-like signal (0-5V) from a signal generator to another equipment (herein 'load'), whose manual states that the input current should be about 10 mA, and 30 mA maximum. As I work with 5 V, I'm thinking I should use a coaxial cable to get the output from the generator, then to connect a 500 Ohms resistance in series with the load, which should give me 10 mA of current.

I would like to know if this is correct, and if there's some safer way to do this, as the equipment I'm trying to feed this signal to is borrowed from another laboratory.

Updated to add the link to the equipment manual (page 34, section 3.13.1) http://www.biomech.hacettepe.edu.tr/manuals/FASTCAM_SA3_HW_Manual_Rev105en.pdf

Comment: Can you link the manual? Most likely, the load equipment is promising not to draw more than 10 mA. It is telling you that its equivalent input impedance is at least 500 ohms, and probably higher. So you don't need to add any series resistance.

Comment: Thanks 'The Photon' for your quick answer. The manual states: "TRIG TTL IN Connector:
The system recognizes an external TTL signal as a trigger during the READY or ENDLESS recording state. Starting and stopping recording (in the selected recording mode) is controlled with this signal. Input voltage is 0V to +12V (H level +4.5V to +12V), positive or negative polarity, pulsewidth is 50 ns or greater.
Operating current is 10 mA recommended, 30 mA maximum." I'll try and link to the manual if I find a pdf version.

Comment: if it says it needs 10mA at 5V then you just give it 5V and it should pull 10mA, if you added a series resistor, you wouldn't have 5V anymore (10mA through 500 ohms is 5V so you'd have no voltage at 10mA as it'd all be across the resistor)

Comment: @user2734434, OK, that is a badly worded manual. Using the term "recommended" does imply it's something you're responsible for. Nonetheless, for a signal input, if they say "TTL in" and input voltage "0 to +12V", you should just apply the voltage and they should be responsible for not drawing more than the specified current.

Comment: Also, please edit your question with the clarification. New readers shouldn't need to read the comments to understand the question.

Comment: @user2734434, not sure what you pulled your quote from, but the phrase "operating current" does not appear anywhere in the PDF you linked to (according to the search function).

Comment: @ThePhoton: ok, so the idea is that its a badly worded manual, and I should just connect the 5V output from the signal generator to the "TTL in" (through a coaxial cable, for instance) and that should work fine without adding a series resistor. Is this correct? If that's the case, please answer my question so that I could mark yours as the answer. Thanks for all your (very useful!) help.

Comment: With the 350-ish ohms plus the input resistance of the isolator, 5 V should be okay. Any higher input voltage and you should add additional external resistance. You could also add resistance with 5 V; the isolator is supposed to switch with just a few mA.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I just wanted to thank you for your answers. Today I tested the connection and it worked just fine. If you would put your comments into an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful if you would describe the "load" in more detail. I would expect that an input in a piece of test equipment is rather high impedance. I guess that the current values stated in your question are properties of the device and not absolute maximum ratings, i.e. the input impedance is such that a current of 10 mA typical, and 30 mA maximum, when a TTL signal is applied.

In any case, a 500 Ohms series resistor won't damage the device. However, if the input is an actual TTL input (i.e. it does not just require TTL-style voltage levels), a 500 Ohms series resistor will prevent the signal generator from pulling the input to Low level.

Comment: @user2734434, please edit the question to add this link. New readers shouldn't have to read comments (especially not comments on answers) to understand the question.

Comment: Also, double check the link. It only gets me a "Page not found" page.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'm sorry, I'm new to the forum. Now the link to the PDF file is updated and checked. And thanks for your help!